# How to support two versions of third-party libraries with different namespaces in onecodebase

Tags: c++, dll, namespaces, shared-libraries, version

I have two versions of third-party C++ libs (lib.so and header files)
In one version all the classes/enums/structs are in namespace "A"
In the other version, they are in namespace "B"
The header and lib.so names are same across both versions

How can I have the same codebase so that I can support both versions. Something like this

```
if (myVersion == "1.0") {
    /* pick all the symbols from namespace "A"*/
} else {
    /* pick all the symbols from namespace "B"*/
}
```

Comment: Support both version at run-time (in one executable), or at compile time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the below code I created two wrapper .so (one with version1 lib and -DVERSION=1 and other with version2 lib and -DVERSION=2)
Let's say they are wlib1.so and wlib2.so

I wrapped the APIs which were in namespace A OR B (depending on what I am compiling with ) in extern "C"

Eg :

```
#define VERSION //your version

extern "C"
{
#if VERSION == 1 //or something like that to mark 1.0.0.0
using namespace A;
#else
using namespace B;
#endif
 void foo_wrapper() {
  foo();
  // wlib1.so will have A::foo() and wlib2.so will have B::foo()
}
}
```

Now at user end, I used something like this at run time:

```
using foo_t = void (*)();
foo_t foo_fp = nullptr;

void init(int ver)
{
std::string lib = "";
if (ver == 1) {
   lib = "wlib1.so";
} else {
   lib = "wlib2.so";
}

void* handle = dlopen(lib.c_str(), RTLD_LAZY);
foo_fp = reinterpret_cast<foo_t>(dlsym(handle, "foo_wrapper"));
}

/* use init(ver) before calling anything */
foo()
{
   foo_fp();
}
```

Thus the user can control at runtime by ver.

Answer (score 1):

What you are suggesting in your code is to determine it at runtime, which is not possible in C++.

If your version is constant you can declare it as macro and use the preprocessor to do the conditioning.

As was said in the comments, `using namespace` is not suggested to use and namespaces aliases can be better.

```
#if VERSION == 1000 //...
namespace My = A;
#else
namespace My = B;
#endif
```

//use My::...

However, if you insist of using `using namespace`,

```
#define VERSION //your version

...

#if VERSION == 1000 //or something like that to mark 1.0.0.0
using namespace A;
#else
using namespace B;
#endif
```

Comment: You could also establish which is the "default" and set a macro value with `-Dmacroname` and do something very similar to this answer only using `#ifdef macroname` and use the appropriate namespace

Comment: [namespace alias](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace_alias) seems more clean than `using namespace`.

Comment: @user4581301 I didn't said it is good, just that it is an optional solution.

Comment: @רועיאבידן Don't mind me. I was cursing my own stupidity. My point is moot now after that edit. Nuking my comments.

Comment: Recommend moving the best option to the top of the answer. Too many people don't finish reading the answer before running off to try the first thing they read.

Comment: The compiler directive #if will require me to have two executables. What I am thinking is to create an adaptor layer and derive two classes from it  (adaptor_ver1 and adaptor_ver2) and compile them as ver1.so and ver2.so which will be using namespaces corresponding to version1 and version2 respectively. Then on runtime, based on the version I can use dlopen the respective library to get the symbols. How does it sound ?